# I have a trip to Dubai booked for next week. With all the tension in the Middle East at the moment, should I reconsider?

Tags: international-travel, safety, event-based-effects, middle-east

Should I reconsider my trip to Dubai next week (Jan 2023) in the wake of all the Middle East troubles at the moment?

Comment: If you plan on waving the Israel, you should probably reconsider that (but I guess thats a plan that requires thought at any time). Overall Dubai is sufficiently far from the areas where the problems are, and aren't (to my knowledge) actively supporting either side, so it's probably about as safe now as at any other time.

Answer (score 4):

There's no real way to answer. We don't know the future, and don't know what bothers you and what doesn't.

At present, Dubai is completely unaffected by the events, and I see no reason to assume that it will be.

Comment: @KateM As user ugoren correctly points out, people have different opinions about stuff — safety, risk tolerance, cost, time, _et al_. Because Stack Exchange sites (including this one) seek declarative answers, opinions are off-topic here.